# Custom back button in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

I have application that is working in popup. Is there a easy way to do manual back button, as popup windows doesn't have them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make use of javascript `history` object  that will work for this

```
function goBack()
  {
     window.history.go(-2)
  }
```

Comment: You where just a second faster then me :-)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `history.go(-1);` will have the same effect.